# Error al tratar de hacer un "DROP TABLE": "ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys"

Tags: sql, oracle

resulta que me encuentro intentando eliminar la siguiente tabla de nombre CIUDAD  con el siguiente código:

```
DROP TABLE CIUDAD;
```

Pero al ejecutar el código me aparece el siguiente error:

```
ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys
02449. 00000 -  "unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to drop a table with unique or
           primary keys referenced by foreign keys in another table.
*Action:   Before performing the above operations the table, drop the
           foreign key constraints in other tables. You can see what
           constraints are referencing a table by issuing the following
           command:
           SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = "tabnam";
```

LA TABLA CIUDAD ES LA SIGUIENTE:

```
CREATE TABLE CIUDAD(
    COD_CIUDAD NUMBER CONSTRAINT PK_CIUDAD PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE_CIUDAD VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE_CIUDAD NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE_REGION VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NOTNULL_NOMBRE_REGION NOT NULL
);
```

Borré todas las tablas con las que se relaciona y aún así no puedo la puedo eliminar.

cualquier ayuda la agradecería.

Saludos.

Comment: tienes relacion de dos tablas por eso no te deja

Comment: pero se supone que si elimino todas las tablas con las que se relaciona , me debería dejar verdad?

Comment: asi es, si solo es para aprender lo puedes hacer  y debes leer sobre relaciones de tablas y haces pruebas

Comment: si por ejemplo tabla A (campo1,campo2) la relacionas con tabla B(campo1,campo2) por medio del campo  tabla A.campo1<->tabla B.campo1 y agregas registros en las tablas no te dejara borrarla por que tienen una relacion

Comment: Lo más probable es que tengas una sentencia similar a esta en tu QUERY ... ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

Answer (score 1):

> Borré todas las tablas con las que se relaciona y aún así no puedo la puedo eliminar.

Evidentemente, todavía existe una relación que no has identificado.

Para encontrar cual(es) tabla(s) tienen una llave foránea que depende de tu tabla `CIUDAD`, puedes ejecutar la consulta siguiente:

```
select distinct c.table_name
  from user_cons_columns cc
  join user_constraints c
    on c.r_owner = cc.owner
   and c.r_constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
   and c.constraint_type = 'R'
 where cc.table_name = 'CIUDAD';
```

En todo caso, con Oracle también puedes forzar el `DROP` usando la claúsula `CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`:

```
DROP TABLE CIUDAD CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

Haciendo el `DROP` de esta manera, Oracle automáticamente elimina cualquier llave foránea que apunta a la tabla `CIUDAD` para que el `DROP` se ejecute sin error.

Comment: Excelente , nuevamente me has ayudado amigo. con tu código se solucionó :D.

Comment: Hola @TAEKCODER, si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, deberías marcarla como aceptada pulsando en el icono ✔ de la parte superior izquierda de la misma.